# How to Send huge amount of data from AJAX to controller in MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using AJAX to send selected check box data to controller. For few records its working properly, but for bulk and heavy record it not sent any data to controller. How to fix this? Currently I am sending 55 records, it will increase in future. Kindly help. Coding below.

```
function Continue() {
  var arrSchd=[];
  var selectedIds="";
  var table = $('#Details').DataTable();

  table.$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index,val){
    var SchdId=$(this).val();
    arrSchd.push(SchdId);
  })

  if(arrSchd.length!=0){
    selectedIds=arrSchd.toString();
    WaitCursorStart();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/MultipleEdit/MultiEditChange",
      data:{"selectedIds":selectedIds,"STime": $('#STime').val(),"ETime": $('#ETime').val()},
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: 'application/json;',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (result) {
        if (result.success == 'success') {
          //some process here
        } else {
          //some process here
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I even tried with `type:'POST'` also. Still not working for huge data.

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: I never get any exception. I used loading cursor gif before sending data and the cursor will stopped after data come back either with success or fail result. now the loading cursor runs only, so I debug using firebug, I found data is not sending to controller

Comment: If selected record is few means,its working properly

Comment: any console error ?

Comment: No.no error is pop up or shown

Comment: How are your data "huge"? Are any of the variables shown in the ajax.data array/objects?

Comment: I Collected Selected Id's in Array then convert the array in to string in above function then I send those string as `selectedIds` to controller. FYI, Each Id is 10 digit unique string.

Comment: That doesn't sound so big. How many KB? I bet most file uploads are bigger. Size is unlikely to be the issue, except if your querystring gets too long. You should definitely use POST for this. Make sure your Action method has the [HttpPost] attribute on it. And remove contentType: 'application/json;'. If you still have a problem, show us your controller method.

Comment: Don't understand why you don't send a raw array instead.

Comment: @ADyson Thank You much as per your one its working. I updated my answer below. Can you please explain about that `contentType: 'application/json;' `? What is the use of this one in AJAX. Why we should remove this? then how its working? As I posted my answer below, I gave 1 upvote to ur ans

Comment: @Merigold I can send raw array also. But because of this error I thought may be bcoz of array, So I send as String. If I send as array also, only few records got work.

Comment: @Halim generally MVC seems to prefer to receive data in regular form-urlencoded format rather than JSON (jQuery encodes the data object for you before it sends, using either the default form-urlencoded format, or the format you specify in the contentType option). See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ under the "contentType" option for a bit more detail. P.S. In general, if you don't understand an option, you should probably not use it, or should read the documentation :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed content type and changed my one to POST in both AJAX and Controller. It's working.

My updated answer below

```
function Continue() {
  var arrSchd=[];
  var selectedIds="";
  var table = $('#Details').DataTable();

  table.$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(index,val){
    var SchdId=$(this).val();
    arrSchd.push(SchdId);
  })

  if(arrSchd.length!=0){
    selectedIds=arrSchd.toString();
    WaitCursorStart();
    $.ajax({
      url: "/MultipleEdit/MultiEditChange",
      data:{"selectedIds":selectedIds,"STime": $('#STime').val(),"ETime": $('#ETime').val()},
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (result) {
        if (result.success == 'success') {
          //some process here
        } else {
          //some process here
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```